# How can I extract the salt out of bcrypt hash passwords?

Tags: php, symfony, hash, cryptography, bcrypt

My database stores the bcrypt passwords which means that the salt should be stored with in the password field. I don't want to make a separate field to store the salt by itself when it is not necessary. However when I want to compare passwords that the user sends to me to the passwords stored in the database, I need to hash the incoming password with the same salt. Question: what part of the stored hash is the salt? I think I could just return the salt using simple substr().

```
// password stored in database.
$user->password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 13));


// password from form being compared to form password

$form_password_hash = password_hash($data['form-password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 13));

if($user->getPasswordHash() == $form_password_hash)
{
    $user->setPassword($data['new-password']);
    return new Response("Your password has been changed");
}
```

Comment: No; bcrypt does this for you.

Comment: Every bcrypt library I've used just deals with the whole string, you don't need to pass the salt in seperately.  Surely that's an option?

Comment: Ya I know bcrypt does this for you. The problem that I'm having is that I need to use the same salt that hashed the database password. The bcrypt function automatically picks a "random" salt to use, but I can't use any random salt.

Comment: And if all else fails... Desalination

Comment: The encryption part might use a random salt but the comparison function should take the hash and the string you want to compare it with.

Comment: When you say "bcrypt is generating a new salt" I hear "I am doing this wrong". Post your code.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, which has several ways of using bcrypt in php depending on the version you are runnning:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1248861

Comment: @Mr.Student `password_verify` does that for you. It does not generate a new salt, it uses the salt that's included with the hash you pass in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the `password_verify` function. This function will parse the hashed password string to find the salt and perform the calculation.

```
if (password_verify($data['form-password'], $user->getPasswordHash())) {
    echo 'Password is correct';
}
```

Comment: @owlstead it might not be the answer to the OP's question, but it's the solution to their problem.

Comment: @user1615903 Yeah, that's probably true, so I'll add some info to be able to upvote :)

Answer (score 14):

Salt is the first 22 characters after the third `$` in the hash:

```
$2y$13$<this is the salt, 22 chars><this is the password hash>
```

But you should not manually extract the salt to verify the password - use the [password_verify function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). It takes the password the user entered as the first argument, and the complete hash as the second argument, and handles the salt correctly.

Comment: well it is useful for debugging when you want to recreate the hash yourself using password_hash();